# Introducing redux in existing web application (JSP) with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsp, redux, react-redux

I'm migrating a web application Java/jsp to a reactjs.

The pages are built with jsp templates, which compose the final HTML.
So I cannot use (yet) Reactjs to render my entire application, but just for render some component into the DOM.

So I have a mixed rendering, like this

```
<html>
</html>
<body>
    <header></header>                 <!-- JSP code -->
    <div id="myComponent"></div>      <!-- this is rendered by react -->
    <article></article>               <!-- JSP code -->
    <div id="myOtherComponent"></div> <!-- this is rendered by react -->
    <footer></footer>                 <!-- JSP code -->
</body>
```

Everyhting works fine so far, so I'm trying to introduce Redux to handle the state, but I got stucked when I should render the `<Provider />` component as the [docs says](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#passing-the-store), since I **don't have an entry point** for my application.

So I tried adding one, wrapping all my app code into a div:

```
<html></html>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <header></header>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </div>
</body>
```

And then in my index.js

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div />
  </Provider>,
  window.document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But of course it doesn't work, all my page is blank now, and the block `<div id="app">` is empty

Does this Provider element must include all my components in order to work? Can I use Redux with this mixed setup?

I'm kind of lost, any help would be great.

Comment: You need to create a single `store` somewhere and pass it to multiple `Provider` components for each of your components that you render separately

Comment: ahhhhh @Ujin i thought i could create just **one** Provider element (dunno why), i'll try out, thank you

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do rn have you go a poc on github? heres my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159594/embedding-react-containers-with-jsp

Answer (score 0):

The Provider component should wrap all the components that will use your Redux store via `connect()`. Redux documentation recommends just wrapping all components in `Provider` because there is no problem since you're just using a single store.

In React you shouldn't need to ever put elements directly in the `body` because this is done dynamically.

Here is an example of what your main application files should look like:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ... some scripts/css...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            // intentionally nothing here. will be dynamically inserted via React later
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

entry.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <header></header>                 <!-- JSP code -->
        <div id="myComponent"></div>      <!-- this is rendered by react -->
        <article></article>               <!-- JSP code -->
        <div id="myOtherComponent"></div> <!-- this is rendered by react -->
        <footer></footer>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

To make an entry point simply add the following to your webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './entry.tsx',
    ...
}
```

This is the barebones of a React-Redux application that you should follow when you are ready to transition.